# How to find the derivative of $F(x)=\sin\left[\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\int_0^{y}\sin^3tdt\right)dy\right]$?

Tags: calculus

I hope you are excellent. I came across this exercise from a book, they ask us to find the derivative with respect to $ x $ of the following function $ F (x) $:

$F(x)=\sin\left[\int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\int_0^{y}\sin^3tdt\right)dy\right]$

But I really don't know how to do it or if the solution can be simplified a bit more. I started from the basic rules of derivation (chain rule) and the fundamental theorem of calculus as follows:

I first solved the integral with respect to $ t $:

$\int_{0}^{y}\sin^3{t}dt=\int_0^y\sin{t}(1-\cos^2{t})dt=-\int_0^y-\sin{t}(1-\cos^2{t})dt$ and doing the variable change $u=\cos{t}$ with $du=-\sin{t}dt$. And if we analyze the new integration limits:

If $t=0$, then $u=\cos{0}=1$,

if $t=y$, then $u=\cos{y}$,

and then we get the new integral:

$-\int_0^y-\sin{t}(1-\cos^2{t})dt=-\int_1^{\cos{y}}(1-u^2)du=\int_{1}^{\cos{y}}(u^2-1)du= \left[\cfrac{1}{3}u^3-u\right]_{1}^{\cos{y}}=\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}-\cfrac{1}{3}+1=\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}+\cfrac{2}{3}$

And substituting the previous result in $ F (x) $:

$F(x)=\sin\left[\int_0^x\sin{\left(\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}+\cfrac{2}{3}\right)}dy\right]$

And proceeding to derive using the chain rule:

$F'(x)=\cos{\left[\int_0^x\sin{\left(\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}+\cfrac{2}{3}\right)}dy\right]}\cdot\left[\int_0^x\sin{\left(\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}+\cfrac{2}{3}\right)}dy\right]'$

And as by the fundamental theorem of calculus we know that:

$\cfrac{d}{dx}\int_a^xf(t)dt=f(x)$, then:

$F'(x)=\cos{\left[\int_0^x\sin{\left(\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{y}-\cos{y}+\cfrac{2}{3}\right)}dy\right]}\cdot \sin{\left(\cfrac{2}{3}-\cos{x}+\cfrac{1}{3}\cos^3{x}\right)}$

Comment: I don't think they're expecting you to evaluate the innermost integral.

Comment: As you already know that $\displaystyle \frac d{dx} \int_a^x f(y)dy = f(x)$, we then have$$F'(x) = \cos \bigg[ \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\int_0^{y}\sin^3(t)dt\right)dy \bigg] \cdot \frac d{dx} \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\int_0^{y}\sin^3(t)dt\right)dy = \cos \bigg[ \int_{0}^{x}\sin\left(\int_0^{y}\sin^3(t)dt\right)dy \bigg] \cdot \sin \left(\int_0^x\sin^3(t)dt\right).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of symbolism helps here. Write $$G(y) =\int _0^y \sin^3t\,dt,H(x)=\int_0^x\sin(G(y))\,dy\tag{2}$$ and then we have $$F(x) =\sin H(x) \tag{2}$$ Then via chain rule and $(2)$ we get $$F'(x) =(\cos H(x)) H'(x) \tag{3}$$ And using FTC on $(1)$ we get $$H'(x) =\sin G(x) \tag{4}$$ and then from $(3),(4)$ we get $$F'(x) =\sin G(x) \cos H(x) $$ and using $(1)$ again we get $$F'(x) =\left(\sin \left(\int_0^x\sin^3t\,dt\right) \right) \left(\cos\left(\int_0^x\sin\left(\int_0^y\sin^3t\,dt\right)\,dy\right)\right)$$